# Change rotateY angle by input range

Tags: jquery, css, range

I got a problem while messing with Codepen.
[Here is my pen](http://codepen.io/XDBoy018/pen/VLevab) that I'm working on.

Here is the mark-up (in Haml):

```
.planet
 -(1...100).each do |i|
  .circle

%input{:type => "range" ,:min => "0.1" ,:max => "360" , :step =>'1',:value => '1' ,:id => 'focal'}/
```

The SCSS :

```
$n:100;
//play with this :D
$angle:22deg;
//////////////////
body{
background: #111;
}
.planet{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
.circle{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border:3px solid ;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  @for $i from 1 through 100{
     &:nth-child(#{$i}){
        @include rotateY($angle * $i); 
        @include animation(sphere 0.8s linear infinite);
        border-color:hsl($i * 360 / $n, 100%, 50%);
        }
      }
   }  
 }
```

Now, what I wanna do is change the `$angle` value according to the value of the input. So that everytime it is dragged, it changes the angle of rotateY and gives a new pattern.

Sorry if my question was too long and please refer to the pen!

Waiting for an answer! :)

Comment: I take it you want to rotate the entire planet? Then why not just set the rotate transform on the planet itself?

Comment: @Ana I'm afraid you're wrong cos I want to change the rotateY angle for each child of the `.circle` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know any Haml, but you should add a data attribute with the starting degrees (`data-starting_degrees=""`) for each circle and then change your javascript to this:

```
$("#focal").on("input", function() {
   $(".circle").each(function(){

       var degrees = parseInt($("#focal").val()) + parseInt($(this).data("start-degrees"));
      console.log(degrees);
       $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + degrees + 'deg)');
   });
});
```

Edit:
Here's a codepen (I've also changed the code a bit):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOdRqx

Comment: Yay! I got what I wanted! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: and yes, you wrote`starting-degrees` in this answer (not in the code) :P

Comment: Somehow Haml converts starting_degrees to starting-degrees, normally starting_degrees would work. Anyway np.